# Calling controller actions using custom routes always directing to same action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am accessing different actions which takes different number of parameters but even on applying custom routing the call to the same action is always take place . 
Controller data-----

```
[System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("Details1")]
    public string Detail1(string Name)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [System.Web.Mvc.ActionName("Details2")]
    public string Detail2(string Name, string secondName)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

custom routes

```
context.MapRoute(
            "M_default",
            "controllername/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "name1",
            "controllername/{Name}",
            new { controller = "controllername", action = "Details1" }

        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "name2",
            "controllername/{Name}/{secondName}",
            new { controller = "controllername", action = "Details2" }

        );
```

the forst route is default ,second route is for details1 ,third route is for details2 .

And I calling these from view $.post whose URLS are as 
URL for Details1 calling

```
"/api/controllername/?Name="+somename+"",
```

URL for Details2 calling

```
"/api/controllername/?Name="+somename+"&secondName="+othername,
```

I had taken reference from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs)

What could be possible solution  . Any suggestion , help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your default route last. I think it's catching everything.

Comment: i tried in that way still the result is same , i had put route in this order details2 , details after that default route .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem lies in how the rules are parsed by the framework.
You must keep in mind that the framework start from the top of your rules list and go down till one condition is matched. Inverting the sequences of your urls should fix your problem

You can also use [this route debugger](http://mvcroutevisualizer.codeplex.com/) to check if all your routes are working correctly

Update:
I mean creating the route like this. And I just saw that you are missing the "api" part. Use the route debugger to check that everything is correct.

```
    context.MapRoute(
        "name2",
        "api/controllername/{Name}/{secondName}",
        new { controller = "controllername", action = "Details2" }

    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "name1",
        "api/controllername/{Name}",
        new { controller = "controllername", action = "Details1" }

    );

    context.MapRoute(
        "M_default",
        "controllername/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

    );
```

That should handle correctly

```
  /api/controllername/somename/someothername
```

and

```
 /api/controllername/somename
```

Comment: inverting the route sequence doesn't work in my condition ...........do u mean same  ??@Iridio